# Suppose i am running a script called RTP.sh and it got stopped.Is there any command to know when a particular process was stopped in ubuntu?

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

Suppose i am running a script called RTP.sh, It got stopped at some point. I would like to know when it got stopped. Is there any command to know when a particular process was stopped in ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve that you have to maintain a log using `date` command in your script file just add this line to end of your script to know the exact time.

```
date +"%T"
```

also you can redirect it to any log file too rather showing it in terminal directly

```
date +"%T" |tee RTP.log
```

Comment: I think he is asking when it was stopped and not how much time it took

Comment: Is that really possible @NachiketKate ?

Comment: Nope but whatever answer you have given is not answering his question.

Comment: you can get start/stop time of a process with some logging enabled.

Comment: Then that should be enabled in his script alone not using any command am I right @NachiketKate

Comment: yes. Thus simple answer to this question according to me is run it again with some logging statements. Without it you cannot get the stop time of a process.

Comment: @NachiketKate now check if this is ok answer for the question or not.